# Android executing simple Asynchronous task via Thread/Runnable/Handler/Looper approach

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-handlerthread

I am tasked with displaying a random number after a 5 second delay using `Thread.sleep(5000)`, on a button click using the `Handler`/`Looper`/`Thread`/`Runnable` approach rather than implementing an `AsyncTask`. My problem is, I'm having issues finding examples online of how to implement this task with the aforementioned approach. So, following common `HandlerThread`/`Looper` related practices how would I implement this simple task that I described above?

As after thoughts (I mainly want to know about my question mentioned above right now):

- I would like to make sure that multiple clicks of the Button don't restart the process with each click (only once the 5 seconds are up).
- I would like to allow this simple task to be maintained throughout orientation changes, even if the orientation occurs midway through the 5 second delay that occurs via `Thread.sleep(5000)`

After, After thought:

- The Button and TextView that display the random number exist within a fragment that my `MainActivity` calls.

Comment: Is there any particular thing steering you away from using an AsyncTask? Advantage of that is the onPostExecute function which is called on the Main thread for when its done allowing you to change the UI.

Comment: no need for `Thread`s, `AsyncTask`s, `Timer`s etc, just use `Handler#postDelayed`, that's all

Comment: Yea an AsyncTask would definitely be preferred for this sort of thing, but our professor asked us to practice the approach I outlined above as a means to study for the final I assume. It's to practice the scenario where we're loading data from the internet and the button is suppose to act like a "refresh" button

Comment: @pskink the necessity of the `Thread.sleep(5000)` is to simulate some task that will actually take up time.  In the next phase of this practice assignment `Thread.sleep()` will be replaced by some task that actually takes time.. like downloading a picture for instance

Comment: so yes you can use `AsyncTask` or even better `IntentService` but the latter is a bit more complex...

Comment: Did you manage to do it or you still need an answer?

Comment: Yep, I got it done. Thanks very much though andrei